# how to align multiple divs using CSS

Tags: css, layout, html

i have a number containers that i want aligned. This is the code i have so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DphXz/64/)

First of all, when i run this code from my machine, the "day-label" is double the size that it shows on jsfiddle. the next two ("max-points" and "close-points") are stacked on top of each other and are right text to "day-label", this is as i want it.

Now the next three containers i can't seem to get them lined up, the "points-totals" container i want to be like the "day-label" but to the right of the max and close points. then the next two "thirty-points" and "fifty-points" i want next to the totals.

They should all be on the same line but they're not all the same shape.

Does anyone know what i'm talking about or am i confusing the situation?

I think i'll be able to use "top:X" and  "left:X" but i wanted to know if there was an easier way to get them all inline with each other? like the first three containers.

Thanks for the help.

This is a mock up of how i want it to look -

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an image of your idea? I don't follow your description.

Comment: Do you know of a side where i can upload an image ? @WouterJ

Comment: I'm a little lost but here's a stab at what I think you meant: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DphXz/68/. If that's right let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @ragebunny I use tinypic.com but there are much more image host services

Comment: Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/DphXz/69/

Comment: @j08691 Thats close, but they doesn't seem to be inline with each other.The three containers at the bottom need to be moved up.

Comment: I suppose I'll need to see a pic of the intended result to go further.

Comment: yea so you want total div, 30, 50 points div in a line right?

Comment: You'll probably want to be careful with your doctype here to prevent differences in rendering across browsers.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/id7xas/6

Answer (score 0):

use this : [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/NvM82/)

```
.day-point-container
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

.result-headers
{
    background-color: green;

}

.day-label
{
    background-color: lime;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.max-points
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5%;
}

.close-points
{
    background-color: purple;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5%;
}

.points-totals
{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 20%;
    height:10%;
    float: left;
}

.thirty-points
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.fifty-points
{
    background-color: gold;
        width: 10%;
        float: left;
        display:inline;
        float: left;
    }

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
    }

<div class="day-point-container">                
    <div class="result-headers">Title</div>
    <div class="day-label"><h1>1<small>st</small></h1></div>
    <div class="max-points">Max</div>
    <div class="close-points">Close</div>
    <div class="points-totals">Total</div>
    <div class="thirty-points">30 points</div>
    <div class="fifty-points">50</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DphXz/73/)**?

**HTML**

```
<div class="day-point-container">                
    <div class="result-headers">Title</div>
    <div class="day-label"><h1>1<small>st</small></h1></div>
    <div class="max-points">Max</div>
    <div class="close-points">Close</div>
    <div class="points-totals">Total</div>
    <div class="thirty-points">30 points</div>
    <div class="fifty-points">50</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.day-point-container
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

.result-headers
{
    background-color: green;
}

.day-label
{
    background-color: lime;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.max-points
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5%;
}

.close-points
{
    background-color: purple;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5%;
}

.points-totals
{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 20%;
    height:10%;
    float:right;
}

.thirty-points
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10%;
    float:right;
}

.fifty-points
{
    background-color: gold;
    width: 10%;
    clear:right;
    float:right;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but you could try to use the `float` function in CSS, e.g `float:left`here's a link to W3schools page on `float` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp or if you just want them centered you could always try `<center>`

Answer (score 0):

[Update with prettier code](http://codepen.io/andrew-luhring/pen/jeGIl)

Also- dude, what you look like you're trying to do is display [tabular data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html)

If that is the case, there's nothing wrong with using an actual table-- in fact, NOT doing so would be wrong.

## html

```
<section class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
  </header>
  <ul class="point-container">
    <li class="day"><h1>1<span>st</span></h1></li>
    <div class="points">
      <li class="max">Max</li>
      <li class="close">Close</li>
    </div>
    <div class="results">
      <li class="totals">Total</li>
      <li class="thirty-points">30 points</li>
      <li class="fifty-points">50</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

## css

```
//  ==================
//  base
//
//
html{ font-size: 62.5%; }
body{
font-size: 1.6rem;
  font: normal normal 100 1.6rem "Helvetica Neue", sans serif;
  background-color: black;
}
.container{
  width: 90%;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

//  ==================
//  layout
//
//

body,
.container, 
.points, 
.results, 
.point-container{
  display: flex; 
}
.points,
.container{
  flex-flow: column; 
}
.results{ flex-flow: row;}
.day,
.results li{ 
  flex: 1; 
}
.points, 
.results{ 
  flex:3; 
}

.results li{
  text-align: center;
}



//  ==================
//  colors
//
//
.title{ background-color: #008001; }
.day{ background-color: #00ff00; }
.max{ background-color: blue; }
.close{ background-color: purple; }  
.totals{ background-color: orange; }
.thirty-points{ background-color: red; }
.fifty-points{ background-color: gold; }
```

Comment: I really hope somebody gives me props for holdin' it down for the flex box model.